# Do there exist character encodings with inter-character state?

Tags: character-encoding

#### UTF-8 example

One of the great things about UTF-8 is that an decoder can look at a UTF-8 string at *any* point in the string and start decoding. For example, if I have the string "héllo":

```
68 c3 a9 6c 6c 6f
h. é.... l. l. o.
```

I can point a pointer at *any* location in that string *with no other information*, and start decoding. If I land in the middle of a code point, I won't get that code point (unless I seek backwards), but UTF-8's structure gives me enough information to know that I'm in the middle of a code point, seek forward to the next one, and work from there.

#### Shift-JIS example

This isn't true of all encodings. For example, in Shift-JIS, if I drop a pointer randomly in a sequence of:

```
… 83 84 83 84 83 84 83 …
```

If I start decoding on an `83`, I get: "ヤヤヤヤヤ…"

If I start decoding on an `84`, I get: "ссссс…" (which is a sequence of "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES (U+0441)", not an ASCII "c".)

If we assume that I'm always landing on a character boundary, I can decode with no additional state. (If I don't, I can't reliably decode, as I've shown.) But if I am on a character boundary, I need no other state.

#### Weird example

Last, one could construct an encoding (admittedly somewhat pathological) with the following rules:

Assume all bytes are 0x00 – 0x7f, or 0xff. (i.e., a [0x80, 0xfe] byte will never appear)
For any non-`0xFF` byte, just decode that byte like ASCII. If you encounter an `0xff`, encode each following byte as (U+0080 + that byte). At the next `0xff`, start decoding like ASCII again. Here, an `0xff` byte can be thought to change "pages". The important bit is that if I drop a pointer at a random character boundary in this encoding, *I can't decode*, because I do not know if a previous `0xff` byte has occurred. i.e. the string "`!"#¡¢£!"#`", is:

```
21 22 23 ff 21 22 23 ff 21 22 23
!  "  #     ¡  ¢  £     !  "  #
         ^shift up   ^shift down
```

#### Question

**What I'm curious to know:** Do weird encodings like the last example actually exist? (And if so, which?) Said otherwise, given a pointer I know to point at the start of a code point in a string of *arbitrary* encoding, can I reliably decode from that point with no other information?

Comment: This does not sound like a practical programming question. At least the last sentence should be first. And since decoding routines must be based on specific information about the encoding, any real question “can I start at an arbitrary point?” can be solved using that information.

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022 may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Some context: I'm building a string type templated on character encoding. It accepts your basic string operations (concat, append, insert, delete, iterate), but all operations are on Unicode code points, which it then converts to/from the given encoding. I need to know what assumptions I can or can not make about encodings. Specifically, iterators will always point at the start of a code point, but if there are "page shifts" like I've described, I need to either a) store that, and invalidate on insertions or b) just not deal with those codecs.

Comment: @KarolS That's a great example of what I'm looking for, and I'm glad you pointed me to it. You should put it in an answer.